# Why $\frac{2a+2b-4}{5b-4}<1$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, perfect-numbers

I was reading [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.0898.pdf) paper. I didn't understand something on the 5th page:

"We may suppose that $a\geq b>0$. If $b\geq 5$ then $\frac{2a+2b-4}{ab-4}\leq \frac{2a+2b-4}{5b-4}<1$."

Why?  $\frac{2a+2b-4}{5b-4}<1$ is only possible when $2a<3b$ but I can't see any way to deduce that.

Comment: $b$ can't be $1$ because $b\geq 5$

Comment: Then take $\;a=8\,,\,\,b=5\;$:$$\frac{2a+2b-4}{5b-5}=\frac{22}{20}>1$$Still a contradiction to that claim. Something's missing, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that it is a typo. It should be
$$\frac{2a+2b-4}{ab-4}\le\frac{2a+2b-4}{5a-4}<1$$

Comment: Oh my god! Yes. Thank you.